# Как валидировать 2 формы одним валидатором? на laravel,

Tags: php, laravel, валидация

Всем привет. Подскажите пжл.

У меня есть 2 формы:

1. для пользователя который авторизован (1 поле)
2. для пользователя который не авторизован (3 поля)

Вопросы:

- мне нужно сделать валидацию 1го поля и 2го поля

Как я думаю:

- 1. создать 2 валидатора, но как их тогда подключать не через инекцию в контроллере `message(Request $request)` а внизу через if?
- 2. создать 1 валидатор, подключить его через инекцию в контроллере `message(Request $request)` но как тогда и чего написать в самом валидаторе, как там отловить зарег или не зарег пользователь?

```
@if(request()->user())    <!-- клиент зарегистрирован -->

    <form action="{{ route('message_create') }}" method="POST">
        @csrf

        <div>Вопрос</div>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="45" name="text" >{{old('text')}}</textarea>
        @error('text')<label class="error"> {{ $message }}</label>@enderror
            
        <div class="style-button_save">
            <button class="button_save">Сохранить</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    
@else   <!-- клиент без регистрации -->

    <form action="{{ route('message_create') }}" method="POST">
        @csrf

        <div>Имя</div>
        <input type="input" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
        @error('name')<label class="error"> {{ $message }}</label>@enderror
    
        <div>Телефон</div>
        <input type="input" name="phone" value="{{ old('phone') }}">
        @error('phone')<label class="error"> {{ $message }}</label>@enderror
    
        <div>Вопрос</div>
        <textarea rows="10" cols="45" name="text" >{{old('text')}}</textarea>
        @error('text')<label class="error"> {{ $message }}</label>@enderror
        
        <div class="style-button_save">
            <button class="button_save">Сохранить</button>
        </div>
    </form>

@endif
```

В контроллере:

```
public function message(Request $request){
    $message = new Message();

    $message->fill($request->only([
        'user_id',
        'name',
        'phone',
        'email',
        'text',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
    ]));


    if (Auth::check()){     // если пользователь зарегистрирован
        $message->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    }else{                  // если пользователь не зарегистрирован
        //...
    }

    $message->save();

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

```
namespace App\Http\Requests\Message;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ProductRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
             'name',        => 'required|max:60',
             'phone',       => 'required|max:60',
             'email',       => 'required|max:60',
             'text',        => 'required|max:60',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'required'  => 'поле обязательно для заполнения.',
            'max'       => 'максимальное число символов - :max.',
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public function rules()
    {
        // не зарегистрирован
        if($this->user()){
            return [
                'name'          => 'required|max:60',
            ];

        // не зарегистрирован
        }else{
            return [
                'name'          => 'required|max:60',
            ];
        }
    }
```